# ActiveMQ Artemis 2.21 Master/Slave Status

Tags: activemq-artemis

I have installed ActiveMQ Artemis 2.21.0 in a *1 Master/ 1 Slave* cluster with shared store. The cluster works fine, however, I don't know why in the web console in the STATUS section in "Cluster Info" show ***Lives: 2***, when only one Master is Up. The backup node remains at 1, which is correct.

Can you help me with your feedback please?

The master configuration is as follows:

```xml
  <connectors>
    <connector name="artemis">tcp://localhost:61616</connector>
  </connectors>

  <cluster-user>admin</cluster-user>
  <cluster-password>admin</cluster-password>

  <broadcast-groups>
     <broadcast-group name="bg-group1">
        <group-address>231.7.7.7</group-address>
        <group-port>9876</group-port>
        <broadcast-period>5000</broadcast-period>
        <connector-ref>artemis</connector-ref>
     </broadcast-group>
  </broadcast-groups>

  <discovery-groups>
     <discovery-group name="dg-group1">
        <group-address>231.7.7.7</group-address>
        <group-port>9876</group-port>
        <refresh-timeout>10000</refresh-timeout>
     </discovery-group>
  </discovery-groups>

  <cluster-connections>
     <cluster-connection name="my-cluster">
        <connector-ref>artemis</connector-ref>
        <message-load-balancing>ON_DEMAND</message-load-balancing>
        <max-hops>0</max-hops>
        <discovery-group-ref discovery-group-name="dg-group1"/>
     </cluster-connection>
  </cluster-connections>


  <ha-policy>
     <shared-store>
        <master>
           <failover-on-shutdown>true</failover-on-shutdown>
        </master>
     </shared-store>
  </ha-policy>
```

The slave configuration is as follows:

```xml
  <connectors>
    <connector name="artemis">tcp://localhost:61617</connector>
    <connector name="netty-live-connector">tcp://localhost:61616</connector>
  </connectors>

  <cluster-user>admin</cluster-user>
  <cluster-password>admin</cluster-password>

  <broadcast-groups>
     <broadcast-group name="bg-group1">
        <group-address>231.7.7.7</group-address>
        <group-port>9876</group-port>
        <broadcast-period>5000</broadcast-period>
        <connector-ref>artemis</connector-ref>
     </broadcast-group>
  </broadcast-groups>

  <discovery-groups>
     <discovery-group name="dg-group1">
        <group-address>231.7.7.7</group-address>
        <group-port>9876</group-port>
        <refresh-timeout>10000</refresh-timeout>
     </discovery-group>
  </discovery-groups>

  <cluster-connections>
     <cluster-connection name="my-cluster">
        <connector-ref>artemis</connector-ref>
        <message-load-balancing>ON_DEMAND</message-load-balancing>
        <max-hops>0</max-hops>
        <discovery-group-ref discovery-group-name="dg-group1"/>
     </cluster-connection>
  </cluster-connections>


  <ha-policy>
     <shared-store>
        <slave>
           <allow-failback>true</allow-failback>
        </slave>
     </shared-store>
  </ha-policy>
```

The web console image is:

[image: ActiveMQ Artemis web console]

Comment: Thank you so much, changing the address/port solved the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the default `group-address` and `group-port` (i.e. `231.7.7.7` & `9876` respectively) which means *any other broker* on the subnet also using the defaults will join that cluster. I recommend you try using a different group address and/or port and see if you still observe the same issue.